# What do those mean for cheque purposes?

Tags: droit-et-justice, france, économie

I have a cheque in French language. Below the amount field, I have the following two fields: `À` and `Le`. What do those mean? What am I supposed to write in those fields?

Answer (score 8):

The main sentence of a cheque is “*Payez contre ce chèque {montant} **à** {destinataire}*”, where the parts in braces are what you need to fill in (the *montant* (amount) must be filled twice, once written out in words and once numerically). This is from the verb construction *payer quelque chose à quelqu'un* (pay something to somebody). More precisely, the recipient's identity is the *ordre du chèque* ([TLF III.B.2](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ordre)); the complete formula for a cheque is “*Payer à l'ordre de {destinataire}*”.

Like many official documents, just before the signature, you need to fill in “***À*** {lieu} **le** {date}”, i.e. the place (town name) and date where you signed the document. This sentence fragment is from the phrase “*Ce document a été fait à {lieu} le {date}*”, which is never written out in full but only as “*Fait à {lieu} le {date}*” or just “à {lieu} le {date}*”.

See [How do I pay with a French cheque?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/683/how-do-i-pay-with-a-french-cheque/710#710) for a more complete guide to filling a French cheque.

Comment: It is worth noting that _{date}_ is mandatory but _{lieu}_ is not.